# Where should I put external service calls in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just wondering where should I put the code making external service calls in my MVC application?

In the book "Exam Ref 70-486: Developing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Applications", they suggested that the service calls had to be included in the **Model** code. However, in my opinion, the service calls must be put inside a proxy class like the one below, so we can modify the service calls later if we need to:

```
public class ExternalServiceProxy
{
  public void DoSomething()
    {
       //Call the external service
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering is my thinking correct or what they proposed is right?

Thanks.

Comment: i seem to be agreeing with you, services should be accessible via a proxy. Furthermore in a different project all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controllers are responsible for calling services. However, controllers should be also lightweight, it means it should only contain controller logic, while most of the business or domain logic should be in the services themselves.

So, what I typically do is create a Services folder in the web application and put all service calls there in kind of local proxy services. These are injected in the controller and return the models (`PatientSummary`). In the controller you would then map the returned model to the correct view model (`PatientSummaryViewModel`), which is passed to the view.

```
 namespace WebApp.Services
 {
      public class PatientService
      {
           public List<PatientSummary> FindPatients()
           {
           }
      }
 }

 namespace WebApp.Controllers
 {
      public class PatientController
      {
           private readonly PatientService _patientService;
           public PatientController(PatientService patientService)
           {
                  _patientService = patientService;
           } 
           public ActionResult FindPatients()
           {
                var patients = _patientService.FindPatients(); // return model entities
                // create patient summary view model based on patients model
                return View(patientSummaryViewModel);    
           }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't get too hung up on shoe-horning everything into the MVC "vocabulary". ASP.NET MVC is a web framework, not an all-encompassing architecture design. Feel free to put your external service calls inside proxies, application services, infrastructure services or whatever you fancy.